# html 5 required attribute

Tags: html, codeigniter, validation

when clicking the submit buttom in my form without filling up data, two fields are required at the same time, one is type text , the second is select. Is this normal? I would like to require fields from top to bottom.

my code

```
<form class="well span8" name="contact-form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>main/validar_contacto" method="post">

<div class="row">
<div class="span3">
<label>Nombre</label>
<input type="text" name="fnombre" class="span3" placeholder="Nombre" id="fnombre" required minlength="10" data-validation-minlength-message="muy pocos caracteres">

<label>Apellidos</label>
<input type="text" name="fapellidos" class="span3" placeholder="Apellido" required>
<label>Email </label>
<div class="input-prepend">
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
<input type="email" name="femail" id="inputIcon" class="span2"  style="width:233px" placeholder="Ingrese email" required>
</div>
<label>Télefono</label>
<input type="text" name="ftelefono" class="span3" placeholder="Teléfono">
<label>Celular</label>
<input type="text" name="fcelular" class="span3" placeholder="Celular">

<label>Ciudad</label>
<input type="text" name="fciudad" class="span3" placeholder="Ciudad" required>

<label>Dirigido a:
<select id="dirigido" name="fdirigido" class="span3" required>
<option value="" <?php echo set_select('fdirigido', '', true);?>>Seleccione:</option>
<option value="ventas" <?php echo set_select('fdirigido','ventas');?>>Ventas</option>
<option value="contacto" <?php echo set_select('fdirigido','contacto');?>>Contacto</option>
</select>
</label>

</div>


<div class="span5">
<label>Mensaje</label>
<textarea name="fmensaje" id="message" class="input-xlarge span5" rows="8" required></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary contact">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

I'm attaching an image with the behaviour being depicted.
[image: two required fields selected]

thanks

Comment: Your HTML is probably the problem.  You forgot an end tag in `<label>Dirigido a:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on browser, 
Firefox and IE 10 highlight all required fields which have not been filled,
where as Google chrome highlights the first empty field.
If you want all browsers to behave similarly then you should do validation by using simple Javascript or JQuery. 
You can also look for JQuery Plugins for validation, they can be customized and are easy to implement.

With a quick google search I found this
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/validate

Comment: HTML5 CR explicitly says in [4.10.21.2 Constraint validation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constraint-validation): “User agents may report more than one constraint violation.”

Comment: Thanks chillfill, actually I'm using http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/ plugin to validate. it uses HTML5 , I'll try Parsley.js